# jQuery setting optional arguments to 0 in jquery function

Tags: jquery

I've got a pretty basic jquery function that accepts two arguments, maxWidth and minWidth. The
arguments check the users browser size and performs an action based upon their browser size.

```
$.fn.browserWidth = function(maxWidth, minWidth) {
  maxWidth = maxWidth || 1100;    
  return document.documentElement.clientWidth >= maxWidth;
  return document.documentElement.clientWidth <= minWidth; 
};
})(jQuery);
```

The first conditional works at a normal browser size:

```
if(browserWidth(1099)){ //do something }
```

However the second conditional always fires but I only want it to fire at the mobile breakpoint

```
if(browserWidth(0,1099)){ //do something }
```

Am I wrong in setting the first argument to zero? Ideally I don't even want the first argument
and just want to check the minWidth in this situation. But there are other instances when I 
just want to check the maxWidth? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: your second `return` will never be reached as you have already returned something above. I think you want: `return document.documentElement.clientWidth >= maxWidth && document.documentElement.clientWidth <= minWidth;`

Comment: Newb question but how would I return both arguments? Can you please include a code sample, newb here.

Comment: just edited comment above

Comment: Why is jQuery even included here? This is a JavaScript question without any jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to accept an object instead:

```
$.browserWidth = function(options) {
  // Returns true if no options are passed
  var result = true;
  var width  = $(window).width();

  if('lowerThan' in options) {
    result = result && (width <= options.lowerThan);
  }

  if('biggerThan' in options) {
    result = result && (width >= options.biggerThan);
  }

  return result;
};
```

Usage:

```
if($.browserWidth({ lowerThan: 1099 }) { // ...

if($.browserWidth({ biggerThan: 1099 }) { // ...

if($.browserWidth({ lowerThan: 2000, biggerThan: 1000 }) { // ...
```